# How to estimate the temperature of a filament?

Tags: voltage, wire, watts, emissions

I would like to know how I can estimate/calculate the temperature of a heated filament.
For example, the filament (rhenium) is 0.2mm in diameter and heated with a voltage of 6.4V and a current of 2.72A (i.e. power=17.4W.)

My second question: How does the temperature of the filament depend on the filament current?

Comment: Consider a [disappearing filament pyrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disappearing-filament_pyrometer).

Comment: Please update your question to include more information as follows: will the filament be in open air, or a liquid or what? Second, how long is the filament? Third, is the filament glowing, and if so, subjectively what color? Third, what are you using the filament for, if you can say.

Answer (score 1):

The method you use will depend on the accuracy you want. As you've used the word 'estimate' in your question title, I presume that you don't need standards lab accuracy. Adding an accuracy specification, or adding the purpose of the equipment to your question, may get you more relevant and focused answers.

The simplest way to estimate is to measure the resistance when cold, and at temperature. This depends on having a graph of resistance versus temperature.

This data is for pure rhenium from Kaye and Laby at the npl.co.uk via the wayback machine

```
temp K  resistivity (10^-8 ohm.m)

  78.2   2.62
 273.2  17.2  
 373.2  24.9
 573.2  39.7
 973.2  63.5
1473.2  84.4
```

There will be errors from the purity of the element, and the fact that the measured resistance is an average of the cool bits of element near the mounts, and the hot bits in the middle. There may be a steady drift in the diameter and so resistance of the element due to degradation of the element, though this should be recoverable by a new cold measurement. There may be a drift in the resistivity of the element material, due to reaction with the atmosphere it is operated in.

The main alternatives are infrared thermometry, and spectroscopy. The latter may be possible fairly cheaply with a diffraction grating and a camera.

For the roughest and dirtiest way, look at the colour of the filament, and interpolate from colour description versus temperature. You will find many tables of colour versus temperature online, generally from artisans who weld, operate kilns, heat-treat metals. Spectroscopy is just a way to instrument this process and make it objective rather than subjective.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Is there no way to just estimate/(roughly) calculate it? I don't want to measure something. I just want to calculate over the thumb, but I miss the right formulas?

Comment: @Mattes see my additions to the answer. Given that you already have V and I at temperature, you need only make one cold resistance measurement, and then interpolate from the figures I've provided.

Comment: Dear Neil, thank you again. The full truth is: I got a power supply for that filament, which directly displays me the voltage I apply together with the current flowing. I turned the voltage from 0 to 7 V and received values for the current between 0 and 3 A. Of course if I plot this, I got the ~R dependency. I didn't measure the resistiance at cold temperature yet, good idea. If I understood you correctly, I can plot the cold resistance value and one of my hot values and then interpolate between those with your data?
Thank you!

Comment: @Mattes There is no possible way for you to know the filament temperature using current nor in measuring its resistance. I can't tell you how much money has been wasted on that idea. This includes tens of thousands of dollars, each, for high precision current sources on that idea. The fact is you need to use pyrometry and traceable standards, at least on a periodic basis, or buy a calibrated filament (and even then, operated properly and according to NIST standards, that only works for a hundred hours or so.)

Comment: @Mattes I worked at FEI/Philips (at Heerenveen) regarding temperature measurement for electron beam lithography (and electron microscopy) and the lifetime of an emitter system (Wehnelt, heated tungsten, various enhanced surfaces using lanthanum hexaboride or other proprietary coatings) is primarily due to its sustained average temperature. Due to the huge expense in replacing an emitter system, a lot of attention is given to finding ways to know and maintain specified emitter temperatures. And I can tell you from personal experience this is NOT EASY TO DO!!

Comment: @Mattes Many customers tried (and failed) to use extremely high precision current drive, in the false belief that doing so would mean they were holding the right emitter temperature. Those customers would replace their USD80k emitter heads every two months or so. Other customers used rigorous methods, including regular use of disappearing filament pyrometry as well as other more expensive, regularly applied calibrations, to maintain a true knowledge of temperature. Said customers replaced their emitter heads every two to three years. Ten degrees too hot meant rapid degradation. So it mattered.

Comment: @jonk I am willing to believe you, but it seems at odds with a few things. First, the technique used to estimate the temperature of the disappearing filament itself is based on measuring its resistance (in essence). So how can we be sure that the OP's filament temp cannot be estimated the same way? Second, if temperature is not the only variable which affects a filament's resistance, what is the other variable? Does it degrade over time? What about for low temp filaments, or just heater wire? I know that UL relies on motor winding resistance to measure temperature. But that is at low temps.

Comment: @mkeith The disappearing filament pyrometer itself is calibrated frequently. But it's really useless for the case I mentioned, by itself. The accuracy needed was too tight. It was just a means for knowing if you are at the same place you were, yesterday. It helped to *cheaply* avoid drift. We used other methods for the absolute emitter temperature, applied every so often. Emissivity (a complex topic) varies over time, sometimes all too rapidly, and had to be re-checked often. Those relying *only* on expensive current sources had nothing but trouble, too. Accuracy is just not an easy problem.

Comment: @mkeith So, for example, say you get 2 years of life if you can hold \$2550\:\text{K}\$. You may only get 2 month's life if you let that drift up to \$2570\:\text{K}\$. You'd get better beam intensity and faster lithography write times (nice to get work done faster) but you'd also pay for it in lifetime. Too low, and write times are too slow. So there was always a push towards higher temperatures to get the speed. But there was a sweet spot that gave you the "best value" approach. And this was very hard to hold over time. People spent a lot of money on this, you can be sure.

Comment: @mkeith I love it when I see tables with values like "\$1473.2\:\text{K}\$!" Do you have any idea how expensive it is to get ***accuracy*** of 50ppm Kelvin at that temperature looking at an extended and oddly shaped object from a distance and with uncertain emissivity, likely through various materials like quartz? If only current could replace that work for you!! (Lots of expensive temperature solutions and consulting would have no business, I guess.) We can place it into a situation, though, where the emissivity is near 1 (integrating sphere.) Which is helpful at times.

Comment: @jonk, that is good stuff. Real engineering. But I still am left with a fundamental question. Does the relationship between resistivity and temperature of the filament change over time? In cases where the requirement is not so strict, can this relationship be relied upon? Or is it possible for a material to have 63.5 Ohm-m at 973.2K on one day, and then the next day, the resistivity at 973.2K will be 50 Ohm-m or 75? I can imagine that in some cases the high temperature may degrade the filament so that its resistivity does in fact change with time. But maybe in some lower temp apps it is ok.

Comment: @mkeith Yes, of course it does. And yes, of course if you relax the strict temperature accuracy requirements then you can get by with cheaper optical methods. One of the first things I learned, many years ago starting out, was that the *only* time you really know a temperature well is when you have an absolutely pure element (of certain types) and let it cool down and freeze. Right at the freeze point and for just a moment, you actually know the temperature accurately. So long as there's no relative motion. ;) Which leaves a lot to be desired in between the few freeze points available to you.

Comment: @mkeith I believe resistivity varies over time. But I'm not expert on platinum RTDs, say. The temperatures I've focused on are above \$700\:\text{K}\$ and not accessible to platinum RTDs (wafer FABs aren't keen when stuff ***touches*** their wafers or gets anywhere near them.) A platinum RTD may drift over time but an expert would have better knowledge. I believe they drift, as everything else I've seen with thermionic emitter systems says they do. But I don't have a global view over all materials in all circumstances. So I'm not sure about all cases. Just more so for those I've experienced.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to measure the temperature of incandescent surface is to compare the colour of the filament of a known lamp.

Adjust the current through the lamp until its filament disappears into the sample.

Approximations of the tungsten filament temperature may by accurate enough from calculations. [Calibration and temperature profile of a tungsten filament lamp](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4b12/23c224e31c688e764b133380797385cbf260.pdf) suggests approx 2% accuracy.

The open access paper "Analytical expressions for thermophysical properties of solid and liquid tungsten relevant for fusion applications" https://doi.org/10.1016/j.nme.2017.08.002 is a goto source of information.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disappearing-filament_pyrometer
[image]

Comment: Damn. @jonk beat me to it.

Comment: No problem. It's nice to see someone using a disappearing filament pyro. Side note: women are better able as females can more finely discriminate among color variations. This isn't just a sick joke. It's true. One of the places I saw this in regular action (aside from using these pyros) was in the case of photographic color-checking back in the day when photolabs converted 35mm film into pictures. The test kit to evaluate if someone could be trained as a color checker was almost never passed by males (I never found one in years trying), only females. Almost all color checkers were women.

Comment: **Totally** off topic, but I wonder how much of that is neurological and how much is physiological in the retina.  As someone with deuteranomalous vision, with sisters who have _very_ acute color vision, I'm wondering if it's not just women, but women who have both forms of green photopsins on their X chromosomes, who passed those tests.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to estimate the temperature of the filament before you even build it. That is, you want to calculate the temperature without making any actual measurements.

The difficulty we have with questions like this is that you really want to solve a heat transfer problem, not an electrical problem. You know how much power you are dumping into the filament and you know that almost all of this power will be converted to heat.

To know the **temperature** of the filament you need to model the flow of heat away from the filament to the surroundings. You need to know the thermal conductivity of the electrical connections to the filament and of any physical supports for the filament. You need to know about the airflow and ambient air temperature. At high temperatures, or in a vacuum, you would also need to calculate the power that is lost through radiation to the surroundings. I can't help you with any of that...you might need a mechanical engineer or a physicist.

Comment: Actually, people who design hot wire cutters have rules of thumb for this. However, the length of the filament needs to be known/specified.

Comment: Obviously in the hot wire cutter case, the temp is based on heat transfer in air. When actually cutting it cools down somewhat due to heat tansfer to the work piece.